# Retrieve the original image (or video) from PHAsset

Tags: ios, swift

With the following code I can retrieve an UIImage from a PHAsset:

```
PHImageManager.default().requestImage(
  for: asset,
  targetSize: size,
  contentMode: contentMode,
  options: options,
  resultHandler: resultHandler)
```

Starting from a PHAsset, how can I retrieve the original unmodified image?

**As "original unmodified" I mean:** On the device the images can be saved as jpeg or heic; when I retrieve UIImage the image is uncompressed and to save it I have to re-encode loosing quality. I'd like to get directly the heic or jpeg.

**Note:** I've found [lots of code](https://gist.github.com/jVirus/2f041bb8b1936093773f0bde42af3a49) that retrieve an URL from a PHAsset, however when calling the `requestContentEditingInput` a `nil` is returned as `contentEditingInput`. (See the code on the link)

Comment: What do you mean by "the original unmodified image"? The PHAsset is not storing a UIImage, so by receiving a UIImage in any manner, you are making a modification. What is it that you actually want?

Comment: @matt please see my edit

Answer (score 0):

You can receive the actual image data directly by calling [`requestImageData`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phimagemanager/3237282-requestimagedataandorientation).